# Limiting UK VAT Number Generation with Faker to 9-digit Numbers

Tags: python, faker

I am trying to generate fake UK VAT numbers with Faker. By default, Faker generates a mix of VAT numbers from businesses (GB followed by 9 digits), government departments (starts with GBGD followed by 3 digits), and health authorities (starts with GBHA followed by 3 digits).

I'd like to limit the generated numbers to only the business type with 9 digits.

You can see the default output of the `fake.vat_id()` function with this example which generates 10 fake UK VAT numbers:

```
from faker import Faker
from faker.providers import company

fake = Faker(locale = "en_GB")
fake.add_provider(company)

vat_ids = []

for i in range(10):
    vat_ids.append(fake.vat_id())
```

I hoped that the `fake.add_provider(company)` would lead to only business numbers being generated but that's not the case.

As a workaround, I added a check to my code which re-generates the VAT number until it matches the business format but this quickly becomes inefficient when generating many VAT numbers.

So, I am hoping to find a solution directly in Faker. I know I can create a custom provider but am worried that this may mess up other parts of my code because I also generate other business information with Faker.

Answer (score -1):

from faker import Faker
from faker.providers import company

fake = Faker(locale = "en_GB")
fake.add_provider(company)

vat_ids = []

for i in range(10):
vat_ids.append(fake.vat_id())